# UIImage and multithreading

Tags: iphone, multithreading

I'm working on an App that read images (frames) from the camera, do some processing with the image then show the result in the UI. The frames from the camera come in a delegate that is called in another thread (i.e not the main thread) and I do all the image processing stuff in this thread and just do a performSelectorOnMainThread: when the image is done.

The problem is, before and after the processing I convert the image to/from an internal format. For those conversions I use CGContext. Since I am getting some weird EXC_BAD_ACCESS I am start to wonder if there is any problem using CGContext in any thread other than main.

Should I just call performSelectorOnMainThread: as soon as I get the frame (the camera API will already call my delegate in another thread) and do everything on the main thread? Or CGContext is fine with multithreading, and the bug is probably something else?

Another problem thing that could be causing the problem: the UIImage is created in the processing thread, and then used (and later released) on the main thread. Can this be causing any Autorealease-pool related problem?

Comment: What kind of CGContext are you using?

Comment: It's a bitmap context, created with CGBitmapContextCreate.

Comment: CGContext is fine on background thread, but normal rules apply.. the code you write must be thread safe. What kind of synchronisation are you using? The UIImage could be more of a problem.

Comment: I call performSelectorOnMainThread when I'm done with the image, so I don't need any synchronization (it will not be touched by two threads at the same time), but I don't know how the reference counting will work with multithreading, maybe thats the problem. I do a retain in before performSelectorOnMainThread (in background thread) and the image is released later in the main thread when it will no longer be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the conversion from the internal format to the UIImage, not in the multithreading, it is OK to use CGContext in background threads. Note that there are some functions frequently used with UIImage that are not thread safe, like UIGraphicsBeginImageContext().